# Проблемы при подключении android socket TCP client к модулю wifi232

Tags: java, android, сокет, stm32

Реализую подключение android устройства по Wi-Fi в режиме TCP client'а к модулю беспроводной связи wifi232 (Waveshare), связанного с платой stm32f4discovery. Сеть находит, но в большинстве случаев приложение не может подключиться, хотя иногда соединение устанавливается и передача данных идет спокойно в обе стороны. В то же время, PC клиент всегда подключается.

Часть приложения, отвечающая за подключение:

```
void Connect() {
    class RunSocketTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            SocketAddress serverAddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            try {
                socket.connect(serverAddr, 5000);
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
            }
            socketThreadRun = new ClientThread();
            socketThreadRun.reasonToRun = true;
            socketThread = new Thread(socketThreadRun);
            socketThread.start();
            tValidateConnection.run();
            return null;
        }
    }
    new RunSocketTask().execute(1, null, null);
}
```

При неудачном соединении вылетает SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться